# How to create IIS 7 Catch all error page

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-express

This is what I want to achieve:
I have created an html page.
I dont want IIS to show all the usual blue and white page to users when an error occurs in any of the websites setup on IIS.
I will prefer if the users are shown my html page instead.
Is there a way to achieve this? I would appreciate a step by step process if possible.

I have read around and followed various steps as to achieve this but it just show my html page. One of these links are below:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771076(v=ws.10).aspx